# Perl system() command doesnt return failure when BCP fails

Tags: perl, ipc

I am importing a file into SQL Server using BCP utility in Perl program.
In the file which I am importing, there is a wrong date format so the Import process fails with following error:

```
SQLState = 22008, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Invalid date format
```

I am executing the bcp command as follows in my perl program.

```
my $myBcp = "bcp.exe" <table name> in <temp file path> -f<format file> -m 1 -h "FIRE_TRIGGERS" -o<log file path>
my $myResult = system($myBcp);
```

When I print `$myResult` it gives me '0'. Since there is an "Invalid date format" error, it should return me a error code.

Can anyone let me know how to catch Invalid Date Format error in my perl program?

Thanks

Comment: I assume that in your real program, the string in `$myBcp` is properly quoted, and not like what you have posted above?

Comment: yes it is properly quoted. I was just giving the format.

Comment: You should never post anything but your actual code, exactly as it appears. And certainly not code that won't compile. It only adds confusion. You should be aware that `system` does not return error codes, only the exit status of the program. See `perldoc -f system`.

Comment: I only reason is I cannot give you my database user names and passwords to any one. So gave the format. Sorry about that.

Comment: You did not give the format, you gave something that looks like pseudo-code, which will give errors such as "Unquoted string 'table' may clash with future reserved word.." How you have quoted the string is vital information in answering your question.

Comment: I said sorry about that. Please let me know if you have any answer to my actual question.

Comment: I already gave you the answer: `system` does not return errors. I was not berating you, I was asking for information about how you quoted the string, since what you posted was not what you actually had. Anyway... seems your question is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should redirect STDERR to STDOUT by `2>&1` as follows:

```
my $myBcp = '"bcp.exe" <table name> in <temp file path> -f<format file> -m 1 -h "FIRE_TRIGGERS" -o<log file path>';
my $myResult = `$myBcp 2>&1`;
print $myResult;
```

Comment: Will this command my $myResult = `$myBcp 2>&1`; work? or Should I use system my $myResult = system(`$myBcp 2>&1`;)

Comment: @user1019072 - Backquotes return whatever the called program printed to STDOUT. System returns just the exit status.

Answer (score 3):

`system()` simply returns the exit status of the program it invoked. If `system()` is returning 0 then that is what the program exited with. It's generally considered polite for programs that indicate errors to then `exit()` with a non-zero status, but this is by no means enforced anywhere. It could just be that the program is poorly designed.

One thing you could do is capture the program's `STDOUT` and/or `STDERR` streams and look for specific patterns, or at least anything at all. If anything is printed on `STDERR` it's a likely guess that an error occurred.

For information on capturing those, see [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aRun), [IPC::Open2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aOpen2) or [IPC::Open3](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aOpen3).